# Is it possible to fetch all events from facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

is it possible to fetch all events from facebook? I know that I can do it for specific user with `events.get`, but does anyone know another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jevgenij, Facebook has millions of events. You have to filter on something. ifaour's code filters to the events for a particular user.

In my experience, this will give you only events which this particular user created or was invited to. Also, it excludes events which this user explicitly declined.

I have also tried querying the feed for a group, and filtering for feed items with "http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=". This seems to work pretty well for getting all events from a group, although you have to explicitly query for each event to get event information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can query the [`event`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) and the [`event_member`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/) tables:

```
SELECT eid,name 
FROM event 
WHERE eid IN (
    SELECT eid
    FROM event_member
    WHERE uid=XXXXXXXXX
)
```